# TableView doesn't call cellsForRow from external datasource

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to setup a Tableview programatically with a datasource which is not the ViewController but the cellsForRow is not called, while number of rowsInSection is called

I tried calling the reloadData() without any result

```
import UIKit
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var activityTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityTable = UITableView(frame: view.frame)
        let list = [Activity(name: "a"), Activity(name: "b")]
        let tableData = ActivityTableHandler(table: activityTable, activityList: list)
        activityTable.dataSource = tableData
        activityTable.delegate = tableData
        view.addSubview(activityTable)

    }
}

import UIKit

class ActivityTableHandler: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private let activityList: [Activity]
    private let table: UITableView
    init(table: UITableView, activityList: [Activity]) {
        self.table = table;
        self.activityList = activityList
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activityList.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = activityList[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should declare tableData outside viewDidLoad and make it a member of `MainViewController`. Since you don't have appropriate value to initialize it do `var tableData: ActivityTableHandler!`. Tell if that works

Comment: It does work, thank you. Could you maybe explain why it needs to be declared beforehand to be called?

Comment: Writing it as an answer along with the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your declaration outside the function and make it a class member.

`var tableData: ActivityTableHandler!`

This is because `dataSource` is a weak property and gets destroyed as soon as the scope of the function (`viewDidLoad` in this case) is over